# adding conv1d layer in my model gives me a dimension error

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am new to python and deep learning. I am trying to make a Keras sequential model in which I am adding a convolutional 1d layer for a RNA sequence of length 20 bases, which I have hard coded as numbers using the Keras hashing_trick function. My input is in pandas dataframe and looks like below

```
 b1  b2  b3  b4  b5  b6  b7  b8  b9  b10  b11  b12  b13  b14  b15  b16  \
```

0     2   2   4   2   3   2   4   2   2    3    2    4    2    4    2    2
1     2   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   3    3    2    3    2    2    2    2
2     2   2   3   3   3   2   2   4   3    4    3    3    3    3    2    2
3     2   4   2   2   2   2   3   3   2    2    2    3    2    2    2    2
4     3   4   4   3   2   2   3   2   4    2    2    2    2    2    2    4
5     2   3   2   2   2   3   2   2   2    3    4    2    2    2    2    4
6     2   4   2   4   4   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2    3    2
7     2   4   3   3   3   4   2   2   4    4    4    4    3    2    3    3
8     2   3   2   2   2   2   4   2   2    4    2    2    2    2    2    4
9     3   2   2   2   2   4   2   3   2    2    2    2    4    2    4    2
10    2   2   4   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    3    4    2    2
11    2   2   3   2   2   2   3   4   4    2    2    4    2    2    2    4

Now my data frame shape is (500 rows,20 columns) and my labels in (500 rows,1 column)

So when I am adding the conv1D layer and specifying the filter as 32 and kernel size as 5, am I doing it right?? because I am getting the error

ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_29: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Since I am not using the conv1d layer as first I am not specifying the shape

What am I doing wrong

please find the code snippet below

```
data = pd.read_csv("Sequence_file.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test_file.csv")
tdf = test[['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','b11','b12','b13','b14','b15','b16','b17','b18','b19','b20']]
df1 = data[['b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','b10','b11','b12','b13','b14','b15','b16','b17','b18','b19','b20']]
label = data[['status']]
tlabel = test[['status']]
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32,activation='relu', input_dim=20))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv1D(32,5, activation='relu',padding='same',use_bias=True))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(df1,label,epochs=10,batch_size=32)
```

Comment: a Dense layer produces 2D output, a 1D Convolutional layer expects 3D data (samples, width, channels), so the output of Dense cannot be the input of a Conv1D. What do you want to do with such structure? (It usually goes the other way).

Comment: You are right. So initially i made the conv1d as my input layer, rest i put the dense layer. But i was having the sane error. i have given input shape as. (500,20,2) which is 500 rows, 20 colmuns and 2 groups( which is there in label dataframe). Do you think this is the issue with the shape iam specifying?? And also the what actually is the kernel argument here?? I have given a random number as 5( in the code)

Comment: The input shape should not contain the samples dimension, so it should be input_shape=(20, 2)